# Flash Workers - Can They Display Images/UI

Tags: flash, actionscript, backgroundworker, worker, busyindicator

I've jumped through all the hurdles and slaved away at the keyboard to make Workers work in Flash Builder. Now I can create a worker, start it, terminate it--the whole nine yards. Awesome.

**My question today is**: Can I use them to draw to the screen? What sort of voodoo do I need to perform to make that happen?

My specific scenario is that I have a long-running operation on the main thread. While that's going on I would like to use a worker to draw a busy indicator over the application. When the long-running operation is done I intend to terminate the worker.

Comment: No, workers cannot display things on the screen. It sounds like you need to refactor the long running operation into a worker and put the busy indicator in the main app. You can send pixels to a worker for it to process, but the worker cannot display them. Check the section "What is accessible from a child Worker?" on [this page](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4423) from Thibault Imbert's blog (Adobe Flash Player product mgr).

Comment: Thanks, Sunil.
This is what I was afraid of. Oh well--I guess you don't always get to take the easy way out. ;)